# Xcode 6 GM version, iPhone 6 simulator, no visible @interface for 'UITapGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'initWithTarget:action:'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognized:)];
```

This code can compile for any simulator in Xcode 5,

but in Xcode 6, it can only compile for simulators with 32 bit CPUs(iPhone 5 and under),

when compiling for simulators with 64 bit CPUs(iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone plus), compiler says:

> no visible @interface for 'UITapGestureRecognizer' declares the
>   selector 'initWithTarget:action:'

But I do have imported `<UIKit/UITapGestureRecognizer>`

What's the problem?

Comment: Does `@import UIKit;` change this behavior?

Comment: @quellish it doesn't.

Comment: I disassembled the 64 bit simulator binary for UIKit and the symbols are definitely there. initWithTarget:action: is inherited from UIGestureRecognizer. If you are not including all of UIKit that may have explained your issue, but the @import would have fixed that. The problem may be with something in your build configuration.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as well. My projects run on everything below the iPhone 5s and fail from iPhone 5s and up.

Comment: Mine only fails when archiving, and only on my build machine on Xcode 6 GM.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Check in your project's "build Settings" under "languages- Modules", Look for 'Enable Modules (C and Objective-C', If its 'YES" change it to 'NO'

Comment: @CarmeloS, what is the value for "Base SDK" in your build settings?

Comment: @ChrisTruman see my answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `Product` > `Clean` menu first.(i.e. <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>)
If it won't help, with <kbd>option</kbd> key, `Product` > `Clean Build Folder...` (i.e. <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>).
At last, remove all derived data directory with `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`.

I think `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/*` made with old (Xcode5) SDK causes this problem.

Comment: Thanks, following these steps indeed helped to solve the issue

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening though? I still see it from time to time, mostly when running on an Xcode server and when building in the Testing configuration. Really annoying, would like to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 3):

For me this started happenning when I updated to xCode GM, and only when 5s, 6, 6+ simulator is selected. All others are fine.
Removing ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

I removed my Xcode 5 bundle and restarted my Mac, then magically it works now, I still don't know the reason however.

Comment: I cleared out my old version of Xcode before installing the GM, still seeing this...

Answer (score 0):

None of the above cache cleaning tricks helped. But when I changed the deployment target to less than iOS 8.1 the error went away.